# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. when update values of hashtable

Tags: hashtable

this code throw exception  while i am trying to update value ,first value only updated and then throw the exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." !!!!

```
        Hashtable hh = new Hashtable();
        hh.Add("val 1",null);
        hh.Add("val 2", null);

        foreach (string dd in hh.Keys)
        {
            hh[dd] = "some_value";
           // MessageBox.Show(dd.Value.ToString());
        }
```

i need to update empty values in hashtables or any equivalent structure that has [key,value]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make copy of hh.Keys, because you are trying to change Hashtable which is invalid operation while enumerating its keys in the foreach loop.

Try this code

```
foreach (string dd in new List<object>(hh.Keys.Cast<object>()))
{
    hh[dd] = "some_value";
    MessageBox.Show(dd);
}
```

Comment: i got this error 'System.Collections.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'!!! ,i am using VS 2005

Comment: Cast is extension method. Try adding "using System.Linq;" or use more up to date version of .NET. Other way you can copy hh.Keys array by your self.