# Iterate over elements in hash and updating its values

Tags: powershell, hashtable

At the beginning I set all hash values to null.
When a name in the hash is equal to a certain name the hash value should be set to 1.

However, I get an error

> collection was modified, enumeration may not execute

Which is really stupid, since I do not change the values for the keys. Any ideas?

```
$Fieldlist = @{
    "Brand Name"   = 0;
    "Product Type" = 0
}
# Loops thru an array
$ArrayOfNames = ("Name1", "Name2", ... ,"Brand Name" ...)
foreach ($FieldName in $Fieldlist.Keys) {
    $Message = $FieldName + " -eq " + $ColName + " ?"
    Write-Host $Message
    if ($FieldName -eq $ColName) {
        Write-Host "-------> Yes, bingo"
        $Fieldlist.$FieldName = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `foreach ($FieldName in @($Fieldlist.Keys)) {...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell updating hash table values in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879871/powershell-updating-hash-table-values-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse your logic. Instead of iterating over the keys of the hashtable and comparing them to a value from `$ArrayOfNames` (I suppose that's where `$ColName` is coming from) iterate over the name array and check if the hashtable contains that key before changing the value:

```
foreach ($FieldName in $ArrayOfNames) {
    if ($Fieldlist.ContainsKey($FieldName)) {
        $Fieldlist.$FieldName = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this one works fine. It is also faster, since I was already making a foreach, so I do only one foreach and the function is also faster.   Great  !!! Thx a lot.