# PowerShell update hashtable values in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, replace, foreach, hashtable

I'm trying to update each value in my hashtable with a string replacement.
I tried solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879871/updating-hash-table-values-in-a-foreach-loop-in-powershell), but to no avail.

My current code generates the values with the required replacement. But how do I get them to replace the values in my hashtable?

```
$mactable = [ordered]@{
    "A" = "11:22:33:XX:YY:10"
    "B" = "11:22:33:XX:YY:20"
    "C" = "11:22:33:XX:YY:30"
    "D" = "11:22:33:XX:YY:40"
    "E" = "11:22:33:XX:YY:50"
}

$octet4hex = "10"
$octet5hex = "16"

foreach($value in $mactable.values){
    $value -replace "XX:YY", ($octet4hex+":"+$octet5hex)
}
```

I tried this (as a mentioned solution):

```
foreach($value in @($mactable.values)){
    $mactable[$key] = $value -replace "XX:YY", ($octet4hex+":"+$octet5hex)
}
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
```

Expected result is:

```
"A" = "11:22:33:10:16:10"
"B" = "11:22:33:10:16:20"
"C" = "11:22:33:10:16:30"
"D" = "11:22:33:10:16:40"
"E" = "11:22:33:10:16:50"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-7.0) and it supports [`Item[Int32]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.item?view=net-7.0#system-collections-specialized-ordereddictionary-item(system-int32)) you can do it with a `for` loop:

```bash
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $mactable.Keys.Count; $i++) {
    $value = $mactable[$i] -replace 'XX:YY', ($octet4hex + ':' + $octet5hex)
    $mactable[$i] = $value
}
$mactable['E'] # Outputs: 11:22:33:10:16:50
```

If however you were using a hashtable instead, you would need to clone it or create a new array from its keys like shown in other answers from the link (`foreach ($key in @($hash.Keys)) { ..`) in order to update it while at the same time enumerating it or you would get the error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

```bash
$mactable = @{
    'A' = '11:22:33:XX:YY:10'
    'B' = '11:22:33:XX:YY:20'
    'C' = '11:22:33:XX:YY:30'
    'D' = '11:22:33:XX:YY:40'
    'E' = '11:22:33:XX:YY:50'
}

foreach ($key in $mactable.Clone().Keys) {
    $value = $mactable[$key] -replace 'XX:YY', ($octet4hex + ':' + $octet5hex)
    $mactable[$key] = $value
}
$mactable['E'] # Outputs: 11:22:33:10:16:50
```

Comment: You *could* also snapshot the hashtable keys into a new array to bypass the "modify while enumerating" issue - e.g. ```foreach( $key in @($mactable.Keys) ) { ... }```. It's basically the same idea, but without cloning the entire hashtable in the process...

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer.I totally missed the fact to put the new value in a variable first and then add it to the mactable. That's why I focussed on the value part in my foreach loop.

The ordered part was optional. So I opted for your latter solution and worked like a charm.