# Powershell - foreach loop is exiting prematurely?

Tags: powershell

Forgive me, but I'm very new to Powershell.  I'm having a problem understanding why my code is abruptly exiting the foreach loop once the code finds the book with an ID called "bk103".  I'm expecting that the foreach loop iterate through the for loop 12 times since there are 12 books in the xml file.  Why is it exiting early?

Thank you!

```
Set-Location 'C:\PowershellPractice\'                                                                        #'

[int]$index = 0

[string] $xmlFilePath=’C:\PowershellPractice\books.xml’

[xml] $xmlContent = [xml] (Get-Content -Path $xmlFilePath)

$newSubNode = $xmlContent.CreateElement("security")
$newSubNode.SetAttribute("Mode", "transport")

$collection = $xmlContent.catalog.ChildNodes

Write-Host "Collection has " $collection.Count " elements in it!"

foreach ($item in $collection){
   Write-Host "In foreach, index is " $index
   if ($item.id -eq "bk103" -OR 
       $item.id -eq "bk105" -OR 
       $item.id -eq "bk108" -OR 
       $item.id -eq "bk109"){
         Write-Host "Found book called " $ $item.id
         $elementCopy = $xmlContent.catalog.book[$index].Clone()
         $elementCopy.AppendChild($newSubNode)
         $xmlContent.catalog.RemoveChild($item)
  $xmlContent.catalog.InsertBefore($elementCopy,$xmlContent.catalog.book[$index])

    }
$index++
}

$xmlContent.Save('C:\PowershellPractice\books-edited.xml')
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error?  Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726137/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-when-update-valu ?

Comment: There's no error at all.

Comment: It exits because you modify the `$collection` you're iterating over

Comment: Thanks Mathias, what is a better to write the code?

Comment: Collect the information you need in the foreach loop without actually modifying `$xmlContent` - then use another loop to iterate over the results from the first one and do the actual removal/add. Will write a proper answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot modify the collection while you're currently iterating over it.

Since you only really need to modify the elements in the collections themselves, I would recommend just doing that (instead of cloning the `book` node and re-attaching it):

```
foreach ($item in $collection){
    Write-Host "In foreach, index is " $index
    if ($item.id -eq "bk103" -OR 
        $item.id -eq "bk105" -OR 
        $item.id -eq "bk108" -OR 
        $item.id -eq "bk109"){
        # Add subnode to matching $item
        [void]$item.AppendChild($newSubNode)
    }
}
```

---

If you ever find yourself in a situation where you cannot modify the element in place, use two loops - one to find the interesting elements, and another one to replace them by iterating over the resulting subset:

```
# collect matching results
$foundbooks = foreach ($item in $collection){
    Write-Host "In foreach, index is " $index
    if ($item.id -eq "bk103" -OR 
        $item.id -eq "bk105" -OR 
        $item.id -eq "bk108" -OR 
        $item.id -eq "bk109"){
        # return matching $item
        $item
    }
}

# now modify based on initial results
foreach($book in $foundbooks){
    Write-Host "Found book called " $ $book.id

    $elementCopy = $book.Clone()
    [void]$elementCopy.AppendChild($newSubNode)
    [void]$xmlContent.catalog.InsertBefore($elementCopy,$book)
    [void]$xmlContent.catalog.RemoveChild($book)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias! I tested this but it still does not work as expected.  What the code does is that it adds the new element to bk109 only but not to the rest of the 3 books (bk103, bk105, bk108)

Comment: I did notice weird behaviour though while I had breakpoints on.  I ran the save command within the last for loop, so that after it adds a child node and removes the original node, it saves the changes to the file.  As I proceeded through the for loop, the new node was added to bk103, but then it moved to bk105 in the subsequent iteration.